# Displaying Symbolic Equations in MATLAB2016b

Tags: matlab

I have MATLAB2016b and am using the Symbolic Math Toolbox.

For something like

```
syms y
f = y^2 + y
```

I get the following output:

f =

y^2 + y

If I use

```
pretty(f)
```

Then I get something a little nicer, but not ideal.

What I would really like is the typical latex style as the output. I believe some versions of MATLAB do this automatically but are there any solutions for MATLAB2016b?

If not, what is the earliest version of MATLAB that I would need for this? The issue is my computer is a MacOS Sierra Version 10.12.6 so the 2020 version is not supported by my computer...

I have done some searching online but can't really find anything informative, some help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do you have access to live scripts in MATLAB R2016b? The output is displayed in LaTeX form when using live `.mlx` scripts over the `.m` files. Also if you have access /license for MATLAB online that may be a solution to using R2020b: [MATLAB Online](https://matlab.mathworks.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works nicely if we use the Live Editor! I was using the Command Window before.

Answer (score 0):

### Using Live Scripts `.mlx`

Using the live editor `.mlx` files will yield LaTeX style results in the command window. Unfortunately, `.m` files will yield the plain text style format. Not sure which MATLAB version introduced live scripts.

[image: Live Script Formats]

**Ran using MATLAB R2019b**